# Перестает работать метод в ASP.NET CORE после публикации на сервере

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

После публикации на сервере Windows Server 2016, методом File Sytem, через Visual Studio 2017 перестает работать метод.

Действие кнопки на view.

```
<form asp-action="CreateWordFile" asp-route-id="@Model.Mains.ETP_MainId">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="СФОРМИРОВАТЬ WORD - ФАЙЛ">
</form>
```

Сам метод:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateWordFile(int id, ETP_Main main)
    {
        main = await _context.ETP_Mains.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ETP_MainId == id); 

        var webRoot = _env.WebRootPath; //явно указываю путь к папке wwwwroot
        var pathEtp = Path.Combine(webRoot, "files", "Etp.docx"); //путь к шаблону
        var pathDoc = Path.Combine(webRoot, "files", "Doc.docx"); //путь к файлу который буду заполнять

        using (WordprocessingDocument  wEtp = WordprocessingDocument.Open(pathEtp, true)) //открываю файл Etp.doc
        {
            string docText = null;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(wEtp.MainDocumentPart.GetStream())) //создаю поток чтения
            {
                 docText = sr.ReadToEnd(); //читаю файл
            }

            using (WordprocessingDocument wDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(pathDoc, true)) //открываю файл в который буду вносить изменения
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(wDoc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream(FileMode.Create))) //создаю поток записи
                {
                    sw.Write(docText); //записываю текст в новый файл
                }
            }
        }
        var pathFile = Path.Combine(webRoot, "files", "Doc.docx");
        return PhysicalFile(pathFile, "application/msdoc", "Doc.docx");
    }
```

Ошибка:

```
http://192.168.0.158/ETP/CreateWordFile/30 
HTTP 404 NOT FOUND
```

Метод не должен переходить по ссылке .../CreateWordFile/30.
Метод должен произвести чтение/запись и начать скачивание файла.

Библиотеки в nuget:

```
DocumentFormat.OpenXml
jQuery
Microsoft.AspNetCore.All
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
```

Comment: Этот код обращается к библиотеке DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll. Установлена ли она на сервере?

Comment: А у вас логирование не сделано? Расставьте хотя бы `Trace.WriteLine();` по методу и настройте запись в файл этих сообщений, чтоб определиться в каком месте проблема.

Comment: @PavelMayorov а как она должна быть установлена? DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll. я подключал через NuGEt. После публикации данная библиотека находится в корневом каталоге опубликованного приложения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема оказалось в том, что docx файл по умолчанию имеет ограниченные права на изменение и запись. После разрешения всем пользователям вносить изменения и производить запись в файл, программа заработала корректно. По ссылке очень хорошо расписано, как предоставить доступ.

[wikihow: удалить статус 'только для чтения' с документа MS Word](https://ru.wikihow.com/%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%81-'%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F'-%D1%81-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0-MS-Word)